# Render a view with multiple view directories

Tags: php, phalcon, mpdf

I have a phalcon app that has multiple submodules implemented. The folder structure looks like this:

```
root
    app
        controllers
        models
        views
    modules
        restaurants
            controllers
            models
            views
        tables
            controllers
            models
            views
        chairs
            controllers
            models
            views
    public
```

The views directory is pointed to the modules folder. This way, when I have to pick a views I can just do: `$this->view->pick('tables/views/index')`.

Now, my problem is that when I want to render a view (ie. get the pure html as a string), I can't seem to be able to do that.

```
$this->view->disable();

$this->view->pick('restaurants/views/pdf');

$html = $this->view->getContent();
$html = utf8_encode($html);

$pdf = new mPDF();
$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$pdf->SetTitle('This is a test');
$pdf->Output('test.pdf', "I");
```

Any way I can do/solve this?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/views.html#stand-alone-component

Answer (score 0):

You can use your module name to set the proper views directory directly into your view service. That way you don't have to use the pick function because phalcon will automatically associate them with your controllers.

```
        $module_name = $di->get('router')->getModuleName();

        $viewsDir = __DIR__."/modules/".$module_name."/views/";

        $view = new View();

        $view->setViewsDir($viewsDir);
```